# Display raw api data with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This should be fairly simple and although I'm new to ko I just don't seem to be able to get a result.

I want to add a function to my view model to call and display an API that simply has html text in it like:

```
<p class="class">This is my text</p>
```

The view/page should call the text using ko and display something like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: myText"></span>
```

I've been using $.getJSON requests inside a function. Really need the simplest way to do this. Thanks Stackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean an AJAX call that loads some text?

You need to set up your View Model, then apply some bindings, and at last set the result of the ajax call.

Remember to set the bind to `data-bind='html:`

```js
document.viewModel = { MyText: ko.observable() };

ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(document.viewModel, document.getElementById("content"));

//make your ajax call and handle the result
//$.getJSON('/some/url', function(data){`
    //document.viewModel.MyText(data);
    document.viewModel.MyText('<p class="class">This is my text</p>');
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <span data-bind="html: MyText"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - must be my app that is causing the issue as: Unable to process binding "html: function(){return MyText }" Message: 'MyText' is undefined;

Comment: Ok so the above worked but when adding my api it gives me a "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element" message? Any ideas? Tried ko.cleanNode($element[0]); with no luck

Comment: the exact problem is that, as the error states, you're applying multiple bindings to a node (or a child node) that was already called with _applyBindings_

Comment: Why don't you show us your code so we can help you better??

Comment: oh and.. `MyText` is not found because the previous binding applied has different view Model and does not contain that variable :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mufb4t29/ so I do get the result "this is my text" but I also get errors - Unable to process binding "with: function(){return dealModel }" and Message: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.; - I can create a new stack and let you answer if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: in that jsfiddle you haven't imported none of the libraries you're trying to use with `require.js` api, and the version of _knockout.js_ you're trying to use (v2.0.0) is not compatible with _require.js_, it's important to use a __working__ example...